# Is there a pattern that is dual to applying single transformation to an infinite stream of elements?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Which is applying stream of transformations to a single immutable element/state. Applicative functor does something like this but for functions of limited arity. It lets you execute them in a separate context where you can gather errors and let it finish in failed state for instance... I'm interested in something more turing complete.

Example might be IDE editor : infinite stream of transformations being applied to editor state.

Apart from the obvious foldLeft/scanLeft with [A => B] elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> applying single transformation to an infinite stream of elements

Is a map.

```
 map f [1..]
```

> applying stream of transformations to a single immutable element/state

Is still map :)

```
 map (`apply` x) [f, g, h ..]
```

where

```
 f `apply` x = f x
```

and the sequence of actions is much more rich. And you might have a custom `apply` function that does more than simply function application.  And there may be some accumulated state, so its a map and a fold. With rich semantics for the incoming stream.

This is an "interpreter" pattern.

- You have a (possibly infinite) "program" -- your stream of actions.
- You have an evaluation function -- your function you apply to each
  action.
- You have an environment/heap/state or other context to
  evaluate each action in.

So you would start by defining the possible actions:

```
   data Exp
          = Action1
          | Action2 Int Bool
          | Action3 ...
```

and an evaluator that interprets each action, with some state:

```
   eval :: State -> Exp -> IO (State, Either Error Result)
   eval st Action1       = .. do something ..
   eval st (Action2 x b) = .. do something else
```

and then finally run this in a loop. Your action `map`.

```
   go :: State -> [Exp] -> IO ()
   go st (act:acts) = do
             (st', er) <- eval st act
             case er of
                 Error x -> .. fail ?
                 Result y -> .. success
             go st' acts
```

And you're on your way.